# View not rendering after foreach loop MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

Goal: I am attempting to populate a table based on a dropdown list using Razor syntax to populate my table.

Summary:  I am passing the model into my View and looping thru each object within my model.  I am able to see the objects populated within the model when debugging the View, however, when the page actually displays, There is nothing in the table and the only thing that is displaying is the dropdown.

Question: What may be the problem with the page rendering?

My view is as follows:

```
    @model IEnumerable<FantasySportsMVC.Models.PlayerDetails>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Position";
    }

    <h2>Position</h2>

    <body>
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlTournaments",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Tournaments, new { id="ddlTournament", name="ddlTournament"})
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="btnGetData" value="Show me some stuff, Yo!" />
        </div>
        <div id="results">
        </div>
        <table id="tbDetails">
            @if(Model != null)
            {
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var player in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@player.LastName</td>
                            <td>@player.FirstName</td>
                            <td>@player.Position</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            }
        </table>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function SendTournamentId() {
        var data = JSON.stringify({ id : $("#ddlTournament option:selected").val()});
        $.ajax({

            url: '/Leaderboard/Position',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {
                //return JSON.stringify($("#ddlTournament option:selected").val());
                $("#ddlTournament option:selected").val(result.d.id);
            }
        });
    }

    $(function () {
        $('#btnGetData').click(SendTournamentId);
    });

</script>
```

My Controller is as follows:

```
    public class LeaderboardController : Controller
        {
        public ActionResult Position()
            {
                ViewBag.Tournaments = GetTournamentDetailsSelectList();
                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Position(string id)
            {
                ViewBag.Tournaments = GetTournamentDetailsSelectList();
                var tournamentId = id;
                var url = ConstructLeaderboardUrl(tournamentId);
                var xmlToJsonUrl = ConvertXmltoJson(url);
                List<PlayerDetails> details = BindDataTablePlayerDetails(xmlToJsonUrl);
                return View(details);
            }
        }

private static List<PlayerDetails> BindDataTablePlayerDetails(string url)
{
    dtAttributeList = new DataTable();
    var details = new List<PlayerDetails>();

    try
    {
        //ConvertXmltoJson(url);

        // Construct Datatable
        dtAttributeList.Columns.Add("Last Name", typeof(string));
        dtAttributeList.Columns.Add("First Name", typeof(string));
        dtAttributeList.Columns.Add("Position", typeof(string));

        // Add rows to Datatable from Json
        for (int i = 0; i < doc.GetElementsByTagName("player").Count; i++)
        {
            dtAttributeList.Rows.Add(
                doc.GetElementsByTagName("player").Item(i).Attributes["last_name"].Value,
                doc.GetElementsByTagName("player").Item(i).Attributes["first_name"].Value,
                doc.GetElementsByTagName("player").Item(i).Attributes["position"].Value);

        }

        // Add rows from Datatable to PlayerDetails
        foreach (DataRow row in dtAttributeList.Rows)
        {
            var player = new PlayerDetails();
            player.LastName = row["Last Name"].ToString();
            player.FirstName = row["First Name"].ToString();
            player.Position = row["Position"].ToString();
            details.Add(player);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    return details;

}
```

Comment: Unless i'm completely misreading that jquery.... when do you load the version of the page with the table rendered in the browser?

Comment: The initial pageload, Position() method, only displays the dropdown.  On the click event, the ajax call is suppose to call the Position(string url) method.

Comment: Right. It calls it, and the HTML that is rendered by View(details) is pumped into your AJAX callback and goes... where?

Comment: It then goes back to the View - Position.  When debugging I'm able to hit the page when it checks if there are any objects in the model.  When objects exist, they run thru the foreach loop, but after it runs thru the foreach the page does not show the table of populated objects.

Comment: Idealy.  I'm not sure if you were asking or telling me what the issue is.

Comment: Fire up your browser console and look at the network traffic coming back from the AJAX call, i suspect you'll see the full version of the page you're expecting.

Comment: You have a dataType mismatch between your AJAX request and action result. You request json but return a html view with model.